# Tkinter listbox entry pagination

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-code

Recently, I tried to find a way to paginate through listbox entries that runs functions that opens frames with forms, tabs or else, but I didn't find it.

Clearly, I wanna create a control panel application which has a side panel which can switch between pages/frames that hold widgets that user will interact with.

this is the code which I wrote to try to achieve this manner:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainWindow() :
    def __init__(self,root):
        # menu left
        self.menu_upper_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#dfdfdf")
        self.menu_title_label = tk.Label(self.menu_upper_frame, text="menu title", bg="#dfdfdf")
        self.menu_title_label.pack()
        self.menu_left_container = tk.Frame(root, width=150, bg="#ababab")
        self.menu_left_upper = tk.Frame(self.menu_left_container, width=150, height=150, bg="red")
        self.menu_left_upper.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        # create a listbox of items
        self.Lb1 = tk.Listbox(self.menu_left_upper,bg ="red", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0 )
        self.Lb1.insert(1, "Python")
        self.Lb1.insert(2, "Perl")
        self.Lb1.insert(3, "C")
        self.Lb1.insert(4, "PHP")
        self.Lb1.insert(5, "JSP")
        self.Lb1.insert(6, "Ruby")
        self.Lb1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.OnClick )   #return selected item
        self.Lb1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, pady=50 )
        # right area
        self.inner_title_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#dfdfdf")
        self.inner_title_label = tk.Label(self.inner_title_frame, text="inner title", bg="#dfdfdf")
        self.inner_title_label.pack()
        self.canvas_area = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, background="#ffffff")
        self.canvas_area.grid(row=1, column=1)
        # status bar
        self.status_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        self.status = tk.Label(self.status_frame, text="this is the status bar")
        self.status.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.menu_upper_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.menu_left_container.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.inner_title_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
        self.canvas_area.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew") 
        self.status_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def OnClick(self,event):

        widget = event.widget
        selection = widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection)
        # print ("selection: ",selection, ": '%s'"% value)
        if value == 'Python':
            self.tabtop()

    def tabtop(self):

        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.canvas_area, width=400)
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tab3 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tab4 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tab5 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab1, text='Login data' )
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab2, text='Permission')
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab3, text='Roles')
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab4, text='Personal data')
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab5, text='Business data')
        self.tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
        self.l2 = tk.Label(self.tab2, text="label 2").pack()
        self.l3 = tk.Label(self.tab3, text="label 3").pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Control Panel")
root.style = ttk.Style()
root.style.theme_use("clam")
user = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If you have an idea to achieve the same manner with a different algorithm please suggest!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you need a different algorithm if what you have is working? Why did you not incorporate the changes suggested by answers to your other question about this code?

Comment: @BryanOakley Unfortunately, I haven't achieved my purpose, It didn't paginate through each other to run functions that shows widgets.

every time I click on an entry it shows widgets over each other although, It already running!

Comment: You're likely not to get any more help unless you can clarify what you're asking. Also, it would help if you reduced your program down a bit more. Do you really need five different tabs and six different items in the listbox to illustrate the problem you are having?

Comment: It is just an example for me! The problem is I'm a beginner in tkinter and I don't know how to implement pagnition through left menu widget. If you tried to run this script you would get no problem when you run function through listbox entry, but when you clicked on it more than one time the function will run more and more without clearing the existing one. The same when you try to fly to another entry in the listbox, functions run without clearing the existing too. Did you get it @BryanOakley ?

Comment: You had an answer to a previous question (which apparently has been deleted). It was a question where you used the word "continuously", and had several people asking for clarification.

Comment: I have edited the question and clarified it and I didn't get any response.

Comment: In this post I identified my problem by request a way to implement pagination method to solve this case.